# TYPO3 8.7 image height not working

Tags: typo3

I use TYPO3 v 8.7, and when I set in BE image height it doesn't get affect in the FE.

https://prnt.sc/ji42ed

Code in FE is

```
<f:media class="image-embed-item" file="{file}" width="{dimensions.width}" height="{dimensions.height}" alt="{file.alternative}" title="{file.title}" />
```

But the {dimensions.height} consists right '300'

Seems the problem in the imagick or in another php extension. Because cropping doesn't work too. But imagick extension is loaded. On my another hosting everything works

What a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 uses the Width as a primary factor. So it gives the natural height according to the width of your image element.

If you have a container that it's width is 300px, then the image, if it is bigger than 300px, will contain itself to the 300 width and it will get the height for the 300px width. No more.

If you need bigger height, then use a bigger photo. From my understanding, you need a full screen image (999px height, this is the only thing i can think of right now).

I hope that helped

Best regards